# How to add block below onepage review after clicking Place Order button in Magento Checkout?

Tags: magento

I am new to magento. I want to add a block after i click place order button. i want to position this block after the checkout_onepage_review? How can I do this? I tried to do it using observer but it did not work.

Thanks in advance

here's my Observer.php

```
class Custom_PaymentModule_Model_Test_Obesrver extends Varien_Event_Observer
{
    public function testObserver($observer)
    {
        $layout = $observer->getEvent()->getLayout();
        $block = $layout->createBlock('Mage_Core_Block_Template','testing',array('template' => 'paymentmodule/redirect.phtml'));
        $layout->getBlock('root')->append($block);
        $observer->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

and here's my config.xml

```
<events>
        <sales_order_place_after>
            <observers>
                <custom_paymentmodule_test_observer>
                    <type>model</type>
                    <class>Custom_PaymentModule_Model_Test_Observer</class>
                    <method>testObserver</method>
                </custom_paymentmodule_test_observer>
            </observers>
        </sales_order_place_after>
    </events>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're hooking into the `sales_order_place_after` event.  This event fires after and order is placed.  However, after an order is placed, Magento redirects to another page, and that new page has no access to the events/actions/state of the previous page.  You'll need to

- examine the page you end up on after an order
- find the full action name layout handle for that page
- add layout handle/update XML rules to add a block to this after-order page.

Comment: thank you alan. but i tried to stop the redirection by editing the opcheckout.js. so basically i am still on the checkout page after click place order

Comment: Even if i stopped the redirection, i cannot add the block.